# Why does AWS S3 and Cloudfront produce 403 error?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, amazon-cloudfront

I'm trying to use S3 to serve images with Cloudfront CDN, but I'm getting a 403 error when I try to access my object with:

cloudfront_id.cloudfront.net/object

Here's what I did:

Created a bucket with S3 and set permissions with Block All Public Access (I also tried with allowing - same issue).

Uploaded an image and "index.html".

Created a Cloudfront Distrubtion with origin name and domain as:

`bucket_name.s3.us-east-1.amazonaws.com`

Origin access:

Origin access control settings, created a control setting and then copied the bucket policy into my S3 policy.

The policy that Cloudfront generated:

```
{
       "Version": "2008-10-17",
       "Id": "PolicyForCloudFrontPrivateContent",
       "Statement": [
           {
               "Sid": "AllowCloudFrontServicePrincipal",
               "Effect": "Allow",
               "Principal": {
                   "Service": "cloudfront.amazonaws.com"
               },
               "Action": "s3:GetObject",
               "Resource": "arn:aws:s3:::redacted_bucket_name/*",
               "Condition": {
                   "StringEquals": {
                     "AWS:SourceArn": "arn:aws:cloudfront::redacted_AWS_account_id:distribution/redacted_distribution_ID"
                   }
               }
           }
       ]
     }
```

I have waited for the Distribution to be deployed.

When I try to access my image, I get 403 error.

Some things I have tried after reading Stackoverflow:

- Added "index.html" to both the bucket and Default root object
- Tried both block all public access and allowed it

Comment: Solved it. For anyone reading this into the future:

It was an issue with HTTPs. 

Go to cloud front and select the relevant distribution. Then behaviors tab, edit the behavior and allow both HTTP and HTTPs.

Then add this policy (if you don't have it) to the S3 bucket:

 {
      "Sid": "PublicReadGetObject",
      "Effect": "Allow",
      "Principal": "*",
      "Action": [
        "s3:GetObject"
      ],
      "Resource": "arn:aws:s3:::YOUR-BUCKET-NAME/*"
    }

Now I just need to fix the certificate.